# Does RabbitMQ connection fallback from SSL to unsecured, if SSL is not available?

Tags: c#, ssl, rabbitmq

I have setup the following connection factory

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory() {
    HostName = this.ApplicationConfigurationManager.QueueHostname,
    UserName = ...,
    Password = ...,
    Ssl = new SslOption
    {
        Enabled = true,
        ServerName = this.ApplicationConfigurationManager.QueueHostname,
        AcceptablePolicyErrors = SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch | SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors
    }
};
```

The `factory` endpoint correctly shows as `{amqp://localhost:5671}`, as 5671 is for SSL, 5672 is for unsecured.

Note that locally I have not yet enabled SSL for RabbitMQ.

What I notice is that when I create a connection:

`using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())`

and inspect the remote endpoint, it shows as `{[::1]:5672}`.

Why? I would expect it to try to connect to `5671` and fail (correctly, as I have not enabled it yet).

Does RabbitMQ `ConnectionFactory` fallback to 5672 (unsecure) if it finds out that SSL (5671) is not enabled?